# session_set_cookie_params() setting two cookies after redirect

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I'm using a slightly modified version of the login scrips found [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL), and have run into behavior I think is coming from session_set_cookie_params() that I do not understand.

I am using sessions, cookies, and header() to redirect users to a login page, then back to the page they requested.  My problem was that, even though the initial page and the login page use the same function to handle sessions and cookies, two separate cookies were being set; one for www.example.com and one for example.com.  This was preventing a session variable set on the initial page from being read after login.

Here is an example of code from any requested page:

```
requireSSL();
sec_session_start();
if(login_check($mysqli) == false) {
    $_SESSION['origURL'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header('Location: https://www.example.com/login.php');
    exit();
}
```

Here are the functions:

```
function requireSSL() {
    if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] != "on") {
        header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
        exit();
    }
}

function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; // Set a custom session name
    $secure = true; // Set to true if using https.
    $httponly = true; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id. 
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies. 
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
    session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_start(); // Start the php session
    session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.     
}
```

Although I was able to "fix" this behavior by explicitly stating a domain in session_set_cookie_params() (e.g. "example.com"), I would **love** to understand why two cookies were being set in the first place.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

---

Why : Because example.com and www.example.com are two different domains for the browser.

---

```
example.com
```

is a higher level domain.

```
www.example.com
```

is a lower level domain, at example.com

Setting your cookies to the higher domain by:

```
setcookie($name, $value, $expire, $path, 'example.com');
```

Also for the session cookie by :

```
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime, $path, 'example.com');
```

Likewise solves the problem because of that.

So they will be valid for both www.example.com and example.com

Take a look at the domain definition on the php manual for [setcookie function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

**Warning**: High level domain cookies are valid and accessible by all pages at lower levels. Cookie for `example.com` will be accesible from `mysubdomain.example.com` too.

So if that is not wanted, you should differentiate the cookie domains.

---

IMHO:

```
header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Instead of sending the header, echo it to see what is going on...

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I'm not sure it answers my question.  I understand the difference between domain and subdomain, but I do not understand why two cookies are being set.  I don't see anything in the manual under setcookie() or session_set_cookie_params() that would lead to this behavior.  For example, does setting www.example.com ALSO set a cookie for example.com?  That would be weird, unwanted, and undocumented.